# can't find pdflatex

Tags: mactex, pandoc, macos

I just upgraded to a new laptop with OS X 11.4 (Big Sur), and now I can't convert LaTeX/Markdown files to PDF anymore. Trying to convert using pandoc produces the following error:

```
pandoc: pdflatex not found. pdflatex is needed for pdf output.
```

I installed the latest 2021 release of BasicTeX, but I can't find pdflatex in the terminal:

```
pdflatex -- version
zsh: command not found: pdflatex
```

But when I try to locate it, I get:

```
locate pdflatex
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/matplotlib/tests/baseline_images/test_backend_pgf/pgf_pdflatex.pdf
/usr/local/texlive/2021basic/bin/universal-darwin/pdflatex
/usr/local/texlive/2021basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/pdflatex.ini
/usr/local/texlive/2021basic/texmf-var/web2c/pdftex/pdflatex.fmt
/usr/local/texlive/2021basic/texmf-var/web2c/pdftex/pdflatex.log
```

Is pandoc looking for pdflatex in the wrong place?
Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: Just curious: Why didn't you install the full version on MacTeX2021?

Comment: @Mico purely for time's sake. I was trying to get up and running quickly, didn't think I needed the full version (I didn't have it installed previously), and the 4GB download was taking quite long.

Comment: in Terminal what does `echo $PATH` and `which pdflatex` return?